# Select count inner join two database

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to show all supplier information sorted by country, including number of names supplied in current month.

Here are the two database and their variables:

1.Supplier: SupplierID, Suppliedname, Country, ReliabilityScore, ContactInfo

2.SuppliedName: SnID, Suppliedname1, Language, Status, Standard, PlaceID,SupplierID, Supplieddate

Here's what I came up with which didn't really work:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT SuppliedName.suppliedname1), Supplier.(*) FROM SuppliedName 
INNER JOIN Supplier ON Supplier.SupplierID = SuppliedName.SupplierID
WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM SuppliedName.Supplieddate)=EXTRACT(MONTH FROM sysdate) AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SuppliedName.Supplieddate)=EXTRACT(YEAR FROM sysdate)
ORDER BY Supplier.Country;
```

Please help!!! Thanks!

Comment: Sample data and the desired output from that data would be useful. Can you [edit] it into your question? And also an explanation of what *didn't really work* means specifically? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you just missed to `GROUP BY` all columns from `SUPPLIER`.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT SUPPLIEDNAME.SUPPLIEDNAME1),
       SUPPLIER.SUPPLIERID,
       SUPPLIER.SUPPLIEDNAME,
       SUPPLIER.COUNTRY,
       SUPPLIER.RELIABILITYSCORE,
       SUPPLIER.CONTACTINFO
       FROM SUPPLIEDNAME
            INNER JOIN SUPPLIER
                       ON SUPPLIER.SUPPLIERID = SUPPLIEDNAME.SUPPLIERID
       WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM SUPPLIEDNAME.SUPPLIEDDATE) = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM SYSDATE)
             AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SUPPLIEDNAME.SUPPLIEDDATE) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE)
       GROUP BY SUPPLIER.SUPPLIERID,
                SUPPLIER.SUPPLIEDNAME,
                SUPPLIER.COUNTRY,
                SUPPLIER.RELIABILITYSCORE,
                SUPPLIER.CONTACTINFO
       ORDER BY SUPPLIER.COUNTRY;
```